# IE8 hangs on print

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8, print-preview

IE8 on my system generally prints a page as expected.
But for one particular page on the application i am developing, when i choose Print or Print Preview, IE8 hangs indefinitely (This doesn't happen on Firefox).

What peculiarity of a particular web page could cause such an issue in IE8?

Answer (score 2):

Though I have not been able to figure out why IE8 hangs, I am pretty sure it has something to do with the complexity of the rendered document.

Therefore, as a work-around, I excluded certain parts of the document through css when it is printing:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    #excludeComplexDiv {display:none;visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

So now IE8 no longer hangs upon giving the print command!